# He will/would go tomorrow

Tags: modal-verbs

> He will go tomorrow.

> He would go tomorrow.

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you looked up uses of _would_?

Comment: I did, but I still need some explanation regarding this.

Comment: @ModernEnglish Is there a specific aspect you're unsure of, or is it the whole thing?

Comment: Can I use it in the same situation? The second one is counterfactual but I need to know how I can use them in different situations.

Comment: "Would" is not always counterfactual (e.g. "I said I would be there - and I will be" or "I said I would be there - and I was"; "I knew he would be here!").

Answer (score 1):

1. "Will" is used to talk about the future: "we will go tomorrow".
2. "Would" is used for (a) the future in the past and (b) the conditional.

1: "We will go tomorrow."

2a: "I said that we would go tomorrow"; "I knew that we would go"; "I thought that we would go"; "I had already decided that we would go."

2b: "We would go tomorrow if we could"; "We would go tomorrow, but we're too busy, unfortunately."

"Would" is also used for polite requests: "I would like an ice cream, please."

Both "will" and "would" are used for invitations ("Will you accompany me?" / "Would you accompany me?").